# Where to put "using" in a vb file of an asp project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am developing an asp website, and in a .vb file I want to connect to database, so I have to use System.Data.SqlClient

P.S: But I don't know where to put the *using* statement. I used to work with c# in asp, and there we put the using statement at the top of the file. But here it says statements should not be outside a method body or multiline lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of the C# `using` statement in this context is `imports`. It goes at the top of the file same as `using` in C#

e.g. `Imports System.Web`

There is also a `using` statement, used to declare disposaible objects

e.g.

```
using (CN as new SQLConnection)
{
...
}
```